# Declare Angular Directives purely in HTML?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, templating

(Highly related to my other question on Programmers.SE:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/280249/whether-to-abstract-small-repeating-code-segments-in-html-templates)

When I want to reuse a few lines of HTML, it is really annoying that I have to write some JavaScript boilerplate in another file just to create a Directive. I really want to create a Directive in mark up in the same HTML file.

Then an idea came to me: I can create a special directive (`custom-tag` below) that declares a directive from HTML.

For example:

```
<custom-tag name="icon" params="{which: '@which'}">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{which}}" />
</custom-tag>
```

Which will translate to some JavaScript like:

```
module.direcrtive('icon', {
restrict: 'E',
scope = {which: '@which'},
template = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{which}}" />',
});
```

And I can call it like

```
<icon which="asterisk" />
```

My question is does something like this already exist in Angular?

(I know this is just reinventing some other templating frameworks, but I am required to use Angular.)

Comment: You can just use inline templates `<script type="text/ng-template" id="template_id.html"> .... </script>` Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but if you just wanna define a scope variable you can use `ng-init="which='asterisk'"`

Comment: @mrak I don't think that's what I want. I actually want to declare a custom directive from HTML instead of from JavaScript.

Comment: The `<script type="text/ng-template" ...` tag is used only to separate the html from the rest of the page. You can put the template for your icon directive there.

Comment: @mrak I will need the ability to pass parameters to the template though, which means I'll still have to declare the Directive in Javascript.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you are doing this all the way around. Isn't it simpler just to create directive in js with template in it? Here you will not need to create " another file just to create a Directive" instead you will have only file. Not html as you wanted but js but result will be same. Only one file.

Comment: @Mior But the main page has to live in an HTML file instead of JS isn't it? So any additional JS to declare directives is always separated from where the directives are actually called.

Comment: Ok but where is modularity? You have everything in one main html file? Have you separate JS file for your page's controller? If so declare directive in there = no additional file (right after controller). If not you have controller's code in <script> tag in html page? if so declare directive in <script> tag. I still think that you are over-complicating simple thing with no actual benefit.

Comment: You'll see my reasoning in the other question linked at the top. The main problem is not the __additional__ file, but that directive declaration currently have to be __separated__ from the call site thus limiting their usefulness in reusing code in a localized context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (afaik) 3 ways to reference a template in angular:

- As already mentioned in the question, one can put the markup directly in the `template` property
- The template can be referenced via `templateId` in a separated file
- The template can be defined within the same page in a `<script type="text/ng-template" id="template_id.html"> .... </script>`.
  and referenced via `templateId: "template_id.html"`. More details on this: [Using Inline Templates in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124767/using-inline-templates-in-angular)

Comment: Hi, my point is to avoid writing JavaScript as opposed to just finding a place to store the template.

Comment: Ok, so you want something like underscore templates? ng-include may be a solution here but I'm not sure about parameters and template location in this case.

Comment: It seems that ng-include can all the things you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20639967/1494048

Comment: Not really, because it doesn't create an isolated scope as in my example so any parameter passing will have to pollute the current scope which is bad. At this point, I think it's clear there's simply no existing solution to this. I'll rest my case and implement it myself then...